# How to import wikipedia xml dump into mongodb?

Tags: php, xml, mongodb, wikipedia

I used this github php code

```
https://github.com/kodekrash/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb
```

get the dataset by

```
wget -c http://wikipedia.c3sl.ufpr.br/enwiki/20150901/enwiki-20150901-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

quite large 12GB

changed the correponding configuration

```
$dsname = 'mongodb://wiki:wiki@localhost:27017/wikipedia';
$file = '../data/enwiki-20150901-pages-articles.xml.bz2';
$logpath = './';
```

and run from the command line

```
php wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php
```

get error:

```
    PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 37: parser error : expected '>' in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): </namespaces> in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():            ^ in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 38: parser error : Premature end of data in tag namespace line 34 in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():  in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 38: parser error : Premature end of data in tag namespaces line 1 in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string():  in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/username/wiki-project/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb/wikipedia.org-xmldump-mongodb.php on line 73
Aborting. Unable to parse namespaces.
```

I have installed

```
php, mbstring, simpleXML, mongodb extensions and mongodb 2.69
```

output of

```
php -m
```

is

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mongo
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

does anyone have idea about this error ? thanks

Comment: But you are a Python programmer, right? If you have the XML output, parse it with SAX, unmarshal the articles to objects and save those objects to MongoDB. Side note: SO is for specific "programming" problems (writing code, that is), not for specific problems with programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `>` character. In the script file, on line 72 replace this line:

```
$chunk = str_replace( [ 'letter">', '</namespace>' ], [ 'letter" name="', '" />' ], $chunk );
```

With:

```
$chunk = str_replace( [ 'letter"\>', '</namespace\>' ], [ 'letter" name="', '" /\>' ], $chunk );
```

That made it work for me!